# How to perform two-sample unequal sized t-test for two np.array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, p-value, t-test

I have two numpy arrays with different sizes that I would like to run a t-test on directly in python to see the p-value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Scipy Library, you can install it using 'pip install scipy'

```
from scipy import stats
print(stats.ttest_ind(arr1, arr2))
```

It returns tuple of calculated t-statistic and two-tailed p-value

[Reference Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html)

Comment: confirmed that this works on elements of different lengths